# Extend Java TreeSet with subtree size

Tags: java, treeset

I would like to extend the Java TreeSet to a Order-Statistics Tree. Therefore my idea was that i store the subtree sizes in every node and manipulate the `add()` and `remove()` methods s.t. the subtree size will be updated too.

I know that there are some data structures (also in Java) which already implement this, but my question is if it is possible to extend the TreeSet Class in a way, that this attribute is stored and updated, whenever I modify the data structure.

Comment: What is an Order-Statistics tree? Are you sure the `subSet()` methods of TreeSet don't do what you want already (since these subsets have a size)

Comment: A Order-Statistics tree includes the size of the subtree in every node. With this information it es easy (log n) to get the i.-th element of a Tree
How computes subSet() the size? I think its just possible by iterate over all elements, so this would not be log n, therefore subSet() is no possibility.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the [source code](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/TreeSet.java), a `TreeSet` has a

```
private transient NavigableMap<E,Object> m;
```

You are surely able to implement `add`, `addAll`, `remove` and such, but the methods of the `TreeSet` mostly just call the underlying Map, which is `private`, thus not accessible to your implementation. As it seems as though an [Order-Statistic-Tree can have a different order than a normal TreeMap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_statistic_tree), this seems impossible to do by extending TreeSet.

#### Using another data structure

You should be able to base your data structure upon [TreeMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html), upon which TreeSet is allegedly based. It

[provides guaranteed log(n) time cost for the containsKey, get, put and remove operations](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html).